# How can I switch tabs programatically from within my ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, tabcontrol

I have a MVVM desktop application. In my View, I have a `TabControl`.

Any suggestions on the best practice to switch to a specific tab by changing a property on the ViewModel?

I suppose it could be done with a `SelectedTab` property, but then the Tabs have to exist in the ViewModel, and the View must bind to the Tabs list in ViewModel. At the moment, the two tabs are static, in the sence that I won't be creating/deleting any dynamically during execution. So I create the tabs in the View, and they represent two different sets of control bound to the same ViewModel, so it's not a case of different tabs for different view model instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try binding to the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) property to switch to a Tab.

Comment: This worked perfectly and is really simple to implement, thanks. I might add that, for a solution adhering to the principles of MVVM more closely, I think one should have a property in your ViewModel denoting OperatingMode, rather than TabIndex. The View can then bind to the OperatingMode, via a Converter that translates the selected OperatingMode (maybe an enumeration?) to a tab index - selecting the appropriate tab in the View for the current Mode. That way, the ViewModel still doesn't care about tabs and views, it just knows what operating mode the user has selected. Something like that.

Comment: or you have a viewmodel for each tab in a collection that you bind to the `ItemsSource` of the `TabControl`. Then you could do what user pickles suggested, or bind `SelectedItem` to the selected viewmodel

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what MVVM framework you're using, but a possible solution is to have a ViewModel for each tab, with a parent ViewModel.

Then the parent ViewModel can activate the relevant child ViewModel, which will then activate the correct View.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not using a MVVM framework, I am coding it directly according to the methodology described by Josh Smith (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). In his example, he does use a ViewModel per tab, which is clever and effective. However, in my case, the two tabs are based on the same ViewModel, it's just two seperate sets of UI Controls for manipulating the same data, so the ViewModel per tab approach won't work here.

Comment: Could you break the ViewModel into 2 separate ViewModels for each tab? Or have 2 instances of the same ViewModel pointing to the same data?

Comment: Both options are theoretically possible, but would add a lot of unintuitive complexity simply for the sake of sticking to the 'proper' MVVM structure. For this application, I don't need my MVVM to be THAT pure - I also launch Dialog Windows from the ViewModels. But I think your comment is something to keep in mind for the design phase of my next project, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create an IsSelected property on your viewmodel that you can databind to the tabitem's IsSelected property

Answer (score 0):

From `MVVM` perspectives ViewModel should NOT be aware of View details like `TabContainer` and so on, so for ViewModel it does not matter whether on underlying View used `TabContainer` or `ListView` control. So consider something straightforward like simple `IEnumerable<IRepresentationItem> Items` to be exposed by ViewModel and then bound to UI items container of the underlying View.

And obviously expose `SelectedItemIndex` property which could be bound to corresponding SelectedTab/SelectedItem Index of UI Items container.