# How to create a 'non-binding' binding in MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, binding

My question is very close to this one:

[How can I switch tabs programatically from within my ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7305476)

But what I want to do is just switch tabs as a courtesy to the user, and not make it binding. (When the user starts a 'scan', I would like to switch to the 'monitoring' tab, but not prevent him changing tabs just because the scan is still running).

I've worked out that setting `mode=OneWay` will avoid the user *stopping* the scan by changing tabs, but my original idea of binding to 'Scanning' doesn't work great because when that gets set to 'false', the tab goes to 'not selected' and I just get a blank rectangle.  I *could* only invoke the 'property changed' when it goes from false to true, but that seems very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deciding that code behind was the best way to go. It's a UI convenience for the user and the ViewModel doesn't need to know anything about it. So I hook into the 'Start' button and switch tabs when it's clicked.