# How to set active tab in MVVMCross TabActivity

Tags: android, mvvm, tabs, tabcontrol, mvvmcross

I want to set the active tab in a View that inherits MvxTabActivity from the ViewModel layer. Is there a suggested means to accomplish this or is there something in the MVVMCross framework I can use that I am missing?
My only plan at the moment is have the View send messages to the ViewModel when the tab changes and have the ViewModel send a message to the View when it needs to change the active tab.
I would much rather be able to bind properties from MvxTabAvtivity to the ViewModel though. E.G. the MvxTabActivity could have an "ActiveTab" property which is a simple string that names a tab and can be two-way bound to a property on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn' out of the box behaviour.

But you can try to do this in several ways:

- using messages (as you suggested)
- using a custom presenter and send changepresentation hints - custom presenters are introduced in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/presenters-in-mvvmcross
- creating and using a custom binding - https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/custom-bindings-in-mvvmcross

I'm also sure other ways might be available.

Do be aware that the concept of changing tab might not fit well in all platforms - eg its unusual for a wp pivot or panorama to change item.

Comment: OK, I get you.... My project is purely Android based at the moment but I think I'll take an approach that covers all bases in the future.... A pattern that matches Pieter Müller's suggestion of "Operating Mode" in his comment on an answer to this question...Cheers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305476/how-can-i-switch-tabs-programatically-from-within-my-viewmodel?rq=1