# MvvmCross: What is the best way to handle tabs in v3 for iOS?

Tags: mvvmcross

I am working on a tabbed main view for both Android and iOS.  I haven't looked at Android yet, but I was wondering what the best way to handle the changing/selection of the tab in MvvmCross v3 for iOS?  One way would be to make a custom presenter to handle the selection of the appropriate view controller via special presentationBundle options.  But then I was thinking that a more MVVM method would be for the view model of the main tabbed view to contain an integer representing the currently selected tab and bind that to the tabbar control in the view.  However, I don't see this in the conference example so maybe I am thinking incorrectly.  Maybe it is because the tabbar control is not bindable??

Comment: I don't think this question is at all clear. Maybe you are trying to ask too much. Maybe you are asking before you've tried anything. For example, you end with "Maybe it is because the tabbar control is not bindable??" but what does this sentence actually mean - what is the 'it' you refer to and what does two question marks mean? There's some useful tips in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - e.g. 'be specific' - also including code and/or diagrams of what you are trying to achieve may help you receive better answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set active tab in MVVMCross TabActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742830/how-to-set-active-tab-in-mvvmcross-tabactivity)